# Java charset="x-iscii-te"

Tags: java, character-encoding, jakarta-mail

Any idea how to handle x-iscii charsets in java? (eg: x-iscii-te).

Content-Type: text/html; charset="x-iscii-te" in an email causes
java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException

Comment: Thanks for the response, how can i know if all the x-iscii* are handled by x-iscii91?

Comment: Actually, you may be out of luck.  It looks like the x-ISCII-* charsets are distinct 8-bit encodings.  Oracle Java only supports x-ISCII91.   Try contacting Oracle Support (assuming you have a support contract).

Comment: Maybe you could do it using http://icu-project.org/download/4.2.html

Comment: Thanks, icu4j supports x-iscii-*